# Passing parameters to winscp.com command line

Tags: command-line, scripting, automation, winscp

I am trying to write a WinSCP script. I tried the example at,
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#parametrized

but the parameter value is not taken by the script.

When the script is invoked as,

```
winscp.com /script=testscript /parameter param1
```

The following occurs:

First,

```
Searching for host
host not found
```

is displayed.

Followed by, actually connecting to the host using the

```
"open command"
```

but the parameter is never substituted.

It still displays as `%1`

Comment: Not sure you still need this information but the proper syntax in the winscp script file would be %1% and not %1.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know which example you are talking about but I will show you some sample code that I have. I hope it helps. This code is all located in a .bat file.

In this example, a variable %folder% is made with the name of today's date in the format of 2/28/2012. I then ask the user for their username and it gets saved in the variable %username%, same with %password%. I then used the %folder% variable to make a directory with a folder named %folder%.

Now we dive into actual 'WinSCP Code'.

I then located the path towards my WinSCP.exe and then called console. After console was called, I connected to my WinSCP server using the 'open' command and the %Username% and %Password% variables.

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
set folder=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%

SET /P username="Enter Username: "
IF "%username%"=="" GOTO Error

SET /P password="Enter Password: "

rem -- Clear Screen to hide password
cls

IF "%password%"=="" GOTO Error
    md C:\Logs\%folder%\int-rpt01\
    "C:\""Program Files""\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console /command "option batch abort" 
    "option confirm off" "open sftp://%username%:%password%@server.server.net:22"
    "get /opt/ibm/cognos/c10_64/logs/cogserver.* C:\CogServerLogs\%folder%\int-rpt01\" "exit"
```

I hope this helps. Any more information on which example you are using and or how you are using it would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But the "/parameter" and "%1%" didn't work for me.

Comment: I would try /parameter=param1 or just param1

Answer (score 4):

For reference, since I just landed here when attempting to work this out myself, the syntax should be:

In your script file:
`put "%1%" %2%`

and then call it from the command line with
`winscp.com /script=script.file /parameter foo.txt bar/`

This will resolve the script to 
`put "foo.txt" bar/`

Answer (score 3):

To pass your parameter to the `open` command, follow it by `%1%`, ideally wrapped to double-quotes:

```
open "%1%"
```

Refer to:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax

See also [parametrized script example](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

---

Also from the behavior of WinSCP (particularly the attempt to open the connection before the `open` command is actually executed), I assume that you are using an old version of WinSCP that does not understand the `/parameter` parameter yet. Make sure, you use the latest version of WinSCP.